# How can I see the execution plan in Oracle NoSql Database?

Tags: oracle-nosql

Like *"Explain Plan"* feature in the Oracle RDBMS to see the `query plan` of the sql queries, What is the `keyword` to get the `query plan` of the queries in `Oracle Nosql database`.

Answer (score 0):

use keyword `show query` to retrieve the query plan of the queries in NoSql Oracle database.

> Example:

```
show query select fname, lname from employe where fname='foo';
```